# Spacesuit for Obligate Neusters

Tags: space, space-travel, sea-creatures

There is a neustonic sophont that has reached space. They are adapted to survive specifically at the surface of the water: If they are removed from the water then their world's gravity (or their spaceship's acceleration) will crush their ventral parts, and if they are submerged totally they'll just drown. They do not have exclusive respiratory orifices, and need their entire dorsum exposed to air. They are around 4-5cm long in size

Their technology is not that far off from our modern spacesuit technology, though they are a little further ahead

Given this technology and biology, how will they make a spacesuit that protects them?

Comment: Neustonic = floating organism like plankton, for anyone else who didn't know it.

Comment: This question is gobbledygook. If you want better answers write the question so it can be read without an encyclopedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fishbowl.**

[image: fishbowl]

Your critters will float, the way they like it.  They will drive the fishbowl around.  An artificial membrane extends from their bodies laterally to the edges of the bowl, which in a zero gravity situation keeps the water below them and the air above.

Answer (score 4):

By replacing the water

Each spacesuit will need to be custom made and probably adjustable, and they have to keep their shapes rigorously the same (putting on muscle being as bad as putting on fat), but can be built to support the body.  Possibly it will use a gel that can be molded to the form for some flexibility.